# Find the number of vertices $n$ of a complete graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I want to find the number of vertices $n$ of a complete graph with at least 950 edges?

So have got this far,

As it is a complete graph degree of each vertex is $(n-1)$
Therefore using, 
$$2E(G)=\sum_{i=1}^n\delta[V_i(G)]$$
$$2\times950=n\times(n-1)$$
$$1900 = n^2 - n$$
$$n^2-n-1950 = 0$$
By solving for $n$,
$$n=44.0918574$$
$$n=-43.0918574$$
Negative answer can be omitted. Is the answer is $44$?.
Or is it $45$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want to solve is not 
$$ \frac{n^2-n}2=950$$
but rather
$$ \frac{n^2-n}2\ge 950.$$
So with exact equality between $44$ and $45$ and the left hand side expression increasing, we see that $n=45$ is the correct answer. Indeed, $K_{44}$ has only $946$ edges.